# My entry box always returns PY_VAR1 value!!though I'm using the .get function

Tags: python, tkinter

please take a look at my code, it's really simple I need to take the value from the entry box and use it in my program and when pressing the add button I print it ,it keeps giving me this value  PY_VAR1?!! wondering what I'm doing wrong!

here's the link for t runnable code for my question [My code returns an empty value for the entry box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226908/my-code-returns-an-empty-value-for-the-entry-box)

```
from Tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    content = StringVar()
    text = StringVar()
    class addcase:
        def mains(self):
            master = Tk()
            master.wm_title("Add")
            bz = Button(master,text="add",command=self.add)
            bz.pack()
            l = Label(master,text="ok")
            l.pack()
            e = Entry(master,textvariable=content)
            e.pack()
            e.focus_set()
            content.set("default value")
            text = content.get()
            master.mainloop()
        def add(me):
                print content.get()
                print text
```

Comment: Most likely, whatever your actual problem is, it has to do with mixing tabs and spaces. The reason I say this is that if I take you source as posted and pasted it into a script, it raises an `IndentationError` at `root = Tk()`. Your actual code may be a little different from what you posted, but if you're mixing tabs and spaces, it will likely be incorrect. Pick a new text editor that either turns tabs into spaces, or shows tabs explicitly (almost everything but Notepad and TextEdit does one or both of those), and run you code with the `-tt` flag.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you fix that problem, your code never creates an `addcase` instance. None of this code ever gets run, no `mainloop1` ever gets called; therefore, all of your code is irrelevant. Please post a [minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you want us to fix.

Comment: Finally, as a side note: This is definitely python 2.x, which means `class addcase:` is explicitly creating a classic class instead of a new-style class. That just adds extra problems for you and everyone trying to help you to deal with for no reason. Always write `class addcase(object):` (or upgrade to 3.x) to eliminate that problem,

Comment: the IndentationError showed cause the code is missing the rest of it!

Comment: Then post a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a random fragment of part of your code that doesn't even be run.

Comment: Meanwhile, if I try to turn your code into an MCVE (by fixing the indentation, and adding code that constructs an `addcase` instance and calls `mains` on it—which is an educated guess at best), it displays a completely empty window, and does not in any way demonstrate the problem you're asking for help with.

Comment: You've now changed your question to be a completely different problem about largely different code. That makes the question and the answer useless to any future searchers, and makes it very hard for anyone else who isn't already involved to figure out what's going on and help you out. Don't do that. If you have a new question, post a new question (and either accept an answer here or post your own answer or explain why you don't think there is a good answer). I'll roll this one back for you.

Comment: I posted a new question, with my new code! thanks

Comment: It's a good idea to put a link to the new question here, and a link to this question in the old one. Otherwise, some people who may not read the whole comment history (most people don't) may think it's a duplicate question and vote to close it, instead of helping you.

Comment: alright,that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't actually given us a runnable example, this is really no more than a guess, but…

When you fix the code so it actually runs, then click the button, it prints this:

```
default value
PY_VAR1
```

If you look at the code, it does this:

```
    def add(me):
            print content.get()
            print text
```

The first line calls `get` on a `StringVar` that you've initialized with `contents.set('default value')`, and never modified again, so of course it prints out `default value`. As far as I can tell, you aren't surprised by this.

This second line doesn't call anything on the `StringVar` named `text`. Just `print`ing a `StringVar`, instead of calling `get()` on it and printing the result, causes it to print the Tk name of the variable. The fact that you've also defined a local variable of the same name within `addcase` is irrelevant. As far as I can tell, this *is* what you're surprised by. But you shouldn't be. The `add` function can't see any local variables you've created in a completely unrelated function.

If you want a value to be shared between different methods of the same instance of a class, store them in an instance attribute, rather than a local variable.

But, more simply, if you just avoided reusing the same name for completely different variables in completely independent scopes, you would probably avoid confusing yourself, and it would be obvious what was going on.

Comment: so I did what u said, I stored the values in instances attribute, to be shared, but still the entry box value now returns an empty value,that's a running version of the code, would u please check it and help me