# My code returns an empty value for the entry box

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Please check the following code;when pressing the add button,the value of text entered in the box, must be entered and printed out using the add function
my olde code used to return PY_VAR1 value for the entrybox , here's a link for my old code [My entry box always returns PY_VAR1 value!!though I'm using the .get function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215713/my-entry-box-always-returns-py-var1-valuethough-im-using-the-get-function)

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class Addcase:
    def mains(self):
        master = Tk()
        master.wm_title("Add")
        self.content = StringVar()
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.bz = Button(master,text="add",command=self.add)
        self.bz.pack()
        self.l = Label(master,text="ok")
        self.l.pack()
        self.e = Entry(master,textvariable=self.content)
        self.e.pack()
        print self.content.get() + "hello"
        master.mainloop()
    def add(me):
            print "this is the entered text"
            print me.content.get()

def calladd():
    z = Addcase()
    z.mains  


def main():
    calling = Addcase()
    root.wm_title("Hello, me")
    b = Button(root, text="Add a case",command=calling.mains)
    b.pack()
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: As a side note, it really helps if you name self `self` instead of `me`, use consistent indentation, and otherwise generally follow Pythonic style (see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for details); otherwise, people may get confused by your code. (For example, I didn't realize at first that `add` was a method; it looked like a local function inside `mains` that got its indentation broken, maybe because you'd mixed tabs and spaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're creating two roots, by calling `Tk()` twice. You can't do that; if you do, all kinds of odd things happen.

In this case, the odd thing that happened is that `self.content` ended up being part of the *first* root, which doesn't get a chance to run until the *second* root finishes its `mainloop`. So, the `StringVar` contents were never getting updated.

(If you looked carefully, you'd also notice that the original window didn't respond properly to events. That has a different effect on different platforms—anything from not refreshing its display if you drag another window across it, to looking fully responsive but not actually doing anything when you click the button until after you've closed the second window.)

If you want to create a new top-level window that runs in the same main loop as the root, you do that by using [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

So, at the top of `Addcase.mains`, instead of doing `master = Tk()`, do `master = Toplevel()`. And then, at the bottom, remove that `master.mainloop()` call.

However, it would really be better to follow a more standard idiomatic pattern for Tkinter. You have a class that's just being used as a holder for that `mains` function. Constructing an instance of the class doesn't do anything; calling that function does everything. It would be clearer to either write the function as a function (in which case `add` would be a local function within that function), or write a class that initializes things in its `__init__` (and possibly inherits from `Toplevel` instead of containing it). Look through the examples in the docs for how to do each way.

Comment: well thank you ,the toplevel window worked perfectly, it gave me the right value, I'm gonna consider the constructor function ,or just turning the class into a function